# how to convert a string into unique integer and vice versa (between 0 to 255) in python3.6

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer, unique

I want to convert a sting like this:

```
input_str = "send_message"
```

to unique integer **between 0 to 255** and also when I decode my **unique integer**, this returned to the same string *"send_message"*.
How to do this converting and should I save unique integers into a json file?

Comment: `hash(input_str) % 256`. Inverse of this function is not possible.

Comment: @Elmex80s I appreciate for your help, I want the same response

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, in general.

From your example it looks like you want allow the string to contain lower-case alphabetic characters and/or the underscore character. That means 27 choices for each character. That means there are 27 x 27 = 729 possible two-character strings. You cannot fit 729 different possibilities into the integers between 0 and 255 and keep them unique--there will be some collisions giving the same results. Therefore you could not decode the integer into a definite string.

This gets worse as the string gets longer, of course.

Comment: @ory-daulton Thanks ,may I ask you how to compute 27 choices?

Comment: @MojtabaArvin: There are 26 letters in the alphabet, `a` to `z`, plus an underscore. That makes 27. The assumption is that you don't  also want spaces, other punctuation, or upper-/lowercase distinctions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have only 256 different strings (because you only have 256 distinct integers), one approach would be to store the strings in a list. When you want to construct the JSON file, look the string up in the list and use its index in the JSON file. When you read an incoming JSON file, use the index in it to retrieve the correct string from the list.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has little practical relevance, but one fun way to build - in one go - a single structure that maps back and forth hashable objects and 0-based contiguous indexes is the following `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d) // 2)
for s in map(str, range(256)):
    d[d[s]] = s

>>> d['3']
3
>>> d[3]
'3'
```